# Update Rails Backend API Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js

I am trying to update a model on my Rails API, which I am successfully able to do with the following code :

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/recoverable_units/{{model.id}}" method="POST">
{{input value= model.name name="name" }}
<br>
{{input type="submit" value="Update"}}
</form>
```

However, I am pretty sure this is not the "correct" or standard way to do this in Ember. Does anyone know of a better way to update my model on my Rails API backend? Maybe need a controller, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should give this a good read. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Basically in Ember you configure adapters to allow your models to know how to talk to your backend Rails API.
So hitting submit on your form doesn't submit to any backend endpoint, it should fire an action that will call `save()` on your model and your model will save to the backend asynchronously according to how you have hooked up your adapter.

If you are using Active Model Serializers, there is a handy Ember addon here https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter that gives you basically everything for free.